# How to exclude all matches in Postgres embedded array using typeorm?

Tags: sql, typescript, postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

I know how to do a search for inclusion in an array:

```
qb.andWhere(
  'tags.id::text[] @> (:tags)::text[]', {tags: ['foo', 'bar']}
)
```

But how do you do the opposite?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply negate it.

```
qb.andWhere(
  'NOT(tags.id::text[] @> (:tags)::text[])', {tags: ['foo', 'bar']}
)
```

If you want to negate the whole WHERE expression of the query, either surround every thing with `NOT` (but the expression can be quite long as everything must be put on a string), or use De Morgan's law, where `not (A and B)` is equivalent to `(not A) or (not B)`.